# wordpress loop returning full content outside of loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a basic wordpress loop to show 3 blog posts + pagination, using `query_posts` to loop these - code attached. The loop and pagination work well, but it's showing a strange glitch: the full page content (for all 3 posts) is also looped and displayed. The full content appears after the pagination and after the `endwhile` closing tag, at the end of all code.

My suspicion is that the loop is somehow not closed, but any closing tags I know to check are already present. My php is still early beginner level and mostly focused on standard wordpress functions, so any suggestions how I can close this up would be welcome.

Note: the loop is using `query_posts` instead of `new WP_Query` because of the pagination, this did not work using any `new WP_Query` loops. I want to get rid of the additional content but keep the base loop the same so the pagination is still functional.

Final note: I have verified the extra content is caused by this loop as removing the loop also removed the content.

```html
<article class="row">
        <?php query_posts(array('posts_per_page' => 3, 'post_type' => 'post', 'paged' => get_query_var('page')));
        if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                <span class="inline-button">Read more <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></span>
          </a>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php endif;?>
  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
  </article>

<article class="row">
        <?php   the_posts_pagination(); ?>
</article>


<!------ in html, all extra generated content will appear here below the above article --->
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolved!

I found the answer and simply closed it adding this to the end:

```html
<?php wp_reset_query() ;?>
```